# Getting the attributes of particular polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-table, fields-attributes, features

I downloaded a shapefile that has demographic data for census tracts for a city - each represented by a polygon in the vector layer.

I can click the attribute table icon to see the whole sheet of attributes for each polygon - but is there any way to click a particular polygon and see its attributes. I tried right-clicking and double-clicking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After choosing the `identify` tool, you can click any of the individual features (polygons) in your vector layer, to see the whole sheet of attributes for each polygon:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, in newer QGIS Versions, you can [open the attribute table to show only the selected feature(s)](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#introducing-the-attribute-table-interface): click on the dedicated icon (see screenshot) or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>:

[image]